# Keycloak managed app. Need to bypass authentication for some pages

Tags: keycloak

Keycloak 12.0.2
I've managed to protect a war. Authentication works fine. Now we have the requirements to publish a couple of pages without any kind of authentication. I don't know where to turn. I tried a bunch of things found there and there, but nobody worked. (contrainsts in web.xml give a 403 in unprotected pages), auth flows, scopes etc not working.

So issue is,
given keycloak protected app, how can I do an helloworld page unprotected by keycloak? Another app only for these pages it's a no-do.